# PHP read specific row

Tags: php, mysql, database, filter

I have a PHP script that displays data read from a MySQL database. I want to filter the output to only show rows where two columns contain specific values. How do I do this?

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: @Valle deutschsprachige PHP- und mySQL-Tutorials gibts hier:  http://www.peterkropff.de/

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WHERE` clause, e.g., `WHERE column1 = 'specific-value1' AND column2 = 'specific-value2'`

Here's a link to MySQL's SELECT syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

(and in German):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html

Answer (score 0):

no idea why you are posting in german on an english site and then translating it to english. But what you need to do is something like "select * from table where column1='val' and column2='val'". Though it sounds like you have a large set of data pulled off already and you want to filter that. I don't see why you shouldn't just query what you need from the database instead of pulling everything off and then filtering.